# table cell edit and update dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-redux

I am new to react. I want to achieve the below functionality in react for a grading table of students. How can I do that?

Please refer to the images.

Change the table cell into an input box

[image: Change the table cell into an input box]

Editable cells in the table

[image: Editable cells in the table]

Below is the snippet I have tried till now:
[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-http-o2lnd)

Comment: What have you done so far? please share relevant codes

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Below is the snippet

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I have updated the description please check

Comment: @MehdiDehghani can you please help

Comment: Please put your code here, btw there is lot of libraries out there which do exactly what you trying to do. sure you can do it yourself but you need to learn more about react first. if you want to do it as practice I recommend do simpler things first.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirements in one of my projects lately and I used [React Data Grid](https://adazzle.github.io/react-data-grid/) library. Basing on your description, it has everything you need.

Comment: without using react-data-grid can I achieve this? if possible can you help me with a small POC

Comment: Why don't you want to use a library that does exactly what you need? There is even a [POC in Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5vy2q8owj4?from-embed). Of course, it is possible to achieve a similar effect even in pure JS, but it would require much more work.